# How to continue routing with DelegateCommand in WPF

Tags: wpf, command, icommand

The KeyBindings in my application are stealing key down messages when I try to use the textbox. So for example:

```
<ribbon:RibbonWindow.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Review.ReviewReviewedCommand}" CommandParameter="Key" Key="Space" />
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Review.ReviewLabelPrivilegedCommand}" CommandParameter="Key" Key="P" />
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Review.ReviewLabelRelevantCommand}" CommandParameter="Key" Key="R" />
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Review.ReviewLabelIrrelevantCommand}" CommandParameter="Key" Key="I" />
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Review.ReviewUnassignDocTypeCommand}" CommandParameter="Key" Key="U" />
</ribbon:RibbonWindow.InputBindings>
```

The commands used are DelegateCommands with ICommand interface.

The problem is that Keys P,R,I,U can't be propagated to any textbox.

Is there a way to continue routing ?

Comment: You should show how you implement one of those commands

Comment: Actually i would think of making the commands Ctrl+r etc instead of changing anything else. I mean when i use Ctrl+C in word i get nothing typed as i expect. If i used just C would i want a c to be written? Guess not. Just asking if you really want it this way

Comment: Yes. I need my DataGrid in a special page to react on this simple shortcuts and need in the other pages to be able to accept I,P,R,U keys. I suppose that will finish to remove this bindings and make some code behind solution.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use `KeyBinding` this not going to work without major hacks. A solution I implemented for this is:

1. Use the `KeyDown` event to capture those keys being pressed (instead of `KeyBindings`). This will be on your code-behind and from there you'll need to switch on the pressed Key to call the required `DataContext's` command (`ReviewReviewedCommand`, `ReviewLabelPrivilegedCommand`, etc).
2. Now you have a different problem. The `TextBox` is getting the input but your key-bound commands are also firing. On the code behind, check the type of `keyEventArgs.InputSource` and ignore the key stroke if it's a `TextBox`.

It should look like this:

```
private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    ICommand command = null;

    switch (e.Key)
    {
        case Key.Space:
            command = ((YourDataContextType)DataContext).ReviewReviewedCommand;
            break;
        case Key.P:
            command = ((YourDataContextType)DataContext).ReviewLabelPrivilegedCommand;
            break;
    }

    bool isSourceATextBox = e.InputSource.GetType() == typeof(TextBox);
    if (command != null && !isSourceATextBox)
    {
        command.Execute(parameter:null);
    }
}
```